# sFlow data generator tool

Tags: simulator

I am developing an application to parse the sFlow data. For this I need a sFlow data generator, which can be used as an input to my application. 
Is there any open source/tools/linux network commands which I can use to generate sFlow data? Platform is Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The [Host sFlow](http://www.sflow.net/) agent runs on Ubuntu and can generate sFlow using iptables and ulog/nflog. Alternatively, you could use [Mininet](http://mininet.org/) to simulate a network and enable sFlow in the virtual switches.

[sflowtool](https://github.com/sflow/sflowtool) is a command line sFlow decoder that you can use to check your parser.

Comment: Please assume that I have zero knowledge in networking and its corresponding tools. Do I have to start/enable any other things after installing Host sFlow?

Comment: Ok. I made necessary changes to config file of hsflowd. I tried to start with hsflowd. but nothing is happening. I did "sudo hsflowd" and then I ran top to see running processes, I don't see the "hsflowd". Please let me know if I miss anything here.